# Order By for two columns of different tables connected with left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, left-join, sql-order-by

I have two table one is `tbl1` having three fields `gadgetid,weight` and `priceperday`.

While second table `tbl2` has columns `promotionsID,gadgetID,promotionalPrice`

Both are connected with left joins mean some gadgets have promotional price as well currently am using order by only for priceperday but now I want to include promotionalprice in order by as well for example now am getting results as

```
gadgetid   priceperday         promotionalprice 

1            32 

9            30

11           26                   23

6            24   

8            21
```

but I want result as follows

```
gadgetid   priceperday         promotionalprice 

1             32

9             30

6             24

11            26                       23

8             21
```

current am using these lines for orderby

```
Select  DT.*
From
( Select
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY

CASE WHEN @SortBy = '1'
THEN (Case when CONVERT(Date, isnull(T.FeaturingStartDate,GETDATE()-1)) <=convert(date,GETDATE()) 
   AND CONVERT(Date, isnull(T.FeaturingEndDate,GETDATE()-1)) >=convert(date,GETDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) END Desc,
CASE WHEN (@SortBy = '2' or @SortBy = '0')
THEN T.PricePerDay END,
CASE WHEN @SortBy = '3'
THEN least(tpf.PromotionalPrice, T.PricePerDay)  END DEsc
,T.CreationTimestamp DESC) AS SysSeq
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `order by least(promotionalprice, priceperday) desc`, or similar.

Comment: got error least is not a built in function

Comment: Use a case expression.

Comment: @AneeqAzamKhan, Are you try my answer? Is it help or any error?

Comment: Hi. This is not clear. Please use enough sentences to clearly say what you mean. Please read & act on [mcve]. In this case, especially the "minimal".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find any `joins` in your current attempt, but as per o/p you need to add `coalesce()` function and do the ordering

```
order by coalesce(promotionalprice, priceperday) desc
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution based on the limited amount of information posted.

Comment: Thank you so much @SeanLange I tried this solution yesterday but got one error instead of search for that error I searched for some other issue but after your comment I tried this one again and got resolved thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT gadgetid,priceperday,promotionalprice
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISNULL(promotionalprice,'')='' THEN priceperday 
            ELSE 
                CASE WHEN promotionalprice>priceperday 
                     THEN priceperday 
                ELSE promotionalprice 
                END 
            END
```

Hope it works fine. If any problem, comment.

Comment: getting this exception "Cannot find either column \"dbo\" or the user-defined function or aggregate \"dbo.IFNULL\", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: I already replace the `IFNULL` with `ISNULL` in the Query. try `ISNULL` instead of `IFNULL`.

Comment: I tried that as well I pasted my sp please have a look

Comment: waiting for your reply.